# Sending gmail using python failing

Tags: python, anaconda, smtplib

**1. pip error**

I did

```
pip install smtplib
```

Then it says

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement smtplib (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for smtplib
```

I confirmed that

```
pip install youtube_dl
```

works. So it's probably not a problem with pip.

**2. Import error**

Anyways, the code I am running is

```
import smtplib

GMAIL_USERNAME = "something"
GMAIL_PASSWORD = "something"
recipient = "something"
body_of_email = "body"
email_subject = "ha"

# The below code never changes, though obviously those variables need values.
session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
session.ehlo()
session.starttls()
session.login(GMAIL_USERNAME, GMAIL_PASSWORD)


headers = "\r\n".join(["from: " + GMAIL_USERNAME,
                       "subject: " + email_subject,
                       "to: " + recipient,
                       "mime-version: 1.0",
                       "content-type: text/html"])

# body_of_email can be plaintext or html!                    
content = headers + "\r\n\r\n" + body_of_email
session.sendmail(GMAIL_USERNAME, recipient, content)
```

But Anaconda prompt shows me error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'SMTP'
```

Can't figure out why this weird thing is happening..

Comment: Are you behind proxy?

Comment: @crisron What do you mean? proxy?

Comment: I meant proxy server

Comment: @crisron I am not using anything like that. I am running this code from my desktop at my home with fast enough Internet connection. Is that why this code is failing?

Comment: Try `pip install --pre smtplib`.

Comment: @crisron   I encounter the same error : " Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement smtplib (from versions: )  No matching distribution found for smtplib"

Comment: Try `pip install --user smtplib`.