# smtplib not available for anaconda distribution?

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I am trying to have my code send me an email once it stops running so I know to go check on it. I have found that a simple way of doing this is by importing the smtplib package, as examples of this code can be seen here: [How to send an email with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270782/how-to-send-an-email-with-python)

However, it does not appear that this package is available using anaconda, as seen here: [Sending gmail using python failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34468952/sending-gmail-using-python-failing)

Can someone please explain how to either download the smtplib package using anaconda in a way that is not explained in the above link, or list documentation to a similar package that helps with this action?

Thanks